How can I make rounded borders inside container which looks same way as the upper borders?

I try to reproduce such a picture with those borders
and css for that
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

But cannot get how to make those lower borders of that heade.
Also inside header isn't close to the borders so I can see white lines.
Can I achieve this only using one container in pure CSS?

A simple box-shadow can do it:


.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 0 0 lightblue;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
<div class="container"></div>




amazing, thank you
